# Use amateur radio frequencies for commercial purpose

Tags: united-states, legal, license, aprs

Can I use amateur radio frequency for commercial purpose (after acquiring ham license), expecting that it would be congestion free band and give me good broadcasting performance compared to other congested ISM bands?

[Being very specific, I am now broadcasting over WiFi 2.4 GHz band. its a broadcast and thus no ACK (acknowledge) return signal is used. Due to congested band its quality is sometimes poor. Can I switch this broadcast to armature radio frequencies e.g. 2300-2310 MHz or 2390-2450 MHz wherever available]

Comment: The answer probably “you would have to make a special request and it would almost certainly be denied”, but please specify the relevant jurisdiction (country) in the tags of your question.

Comment: You'd probably have better luck getting a commercial license, if your purpose is commercial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is answered somewhat in [this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/2318/when-is-aprs-use-considered-commercial) already, and the answer is no.
And I will add some passages about the broadcasting part.

To quote the relevant rule [§97.113](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=9c74c897993f8e8f42eaa5f1fbbaf5a2&node=se47.5.97_1113&rgn=div8):

> §97.113   Prohibited transmissions. (a) No amateur station shall
>   transmit:
>
> (1) Communications specifically prohibited elsewhere in this part;
>
> (2) **Communications for hire or for material compensation**, direct or
>   indirect, paid or promised, except as otherwise provided in these
>   rules;
>
> (3) **Communications in which the station licensee or control operator
>   has a pecuniary interest**, including communications on behalf of an
>   employer, with the following exceptions:
>
> [...]
>
> (5) Communications, on a regular basis, which **could reasonably be
>   furnished alternatively through other radio services**.
>
> (b) An amateur station shall **not engage in any form of broadcasting**,
>   nor may an amateur station transmit one-way communications except as
>   specifically provided in these rules;
>   [...]

There are commercial bands specifically for this purpose. You can apply for a license to use some frequeny exclusively, and you won't have to deal with interference. But of course you have to pay to play.